# How to update but clear existing values in EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework

As an example, say I have a class with 100 properties.  On the first insert all properties are populated with values.

However, I then update the class with only one property value, but I only want to now store this value and clear out all other fields.  I tried checking whether the record exists and if so, then instantiate a new record with the same ID and just change the one field, but it appears that EF preserves all the current/untouched property values in the database.

Is there a concise way of doing this in EF without having to resort to clearing out every field on the update?

Comment: Please provide some code as well. If `Employee` is your entity with `Id, Name, Address, Age etc` and if you wanna update the `Name` and set others to empty, then - (assuming your employee id is 10) - `var employee = new Employee {Id = 10, Name = "Updated Name"}; dbContext.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified; dbContext.SaveChanges();`

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. I think that's because  you are setting the modified state at the class level so it will apply to ALL properties.

Comment: yes, aint that you need?

Comment: or did I read your question wrong? What are you looking for? Should the other values be cleared while update or just update the selected properties alone?

Comment: No you are correct, but there was a missing piece of the jigsaw, namely to dettach and re-attach. See my answer below. Thanks for sending me in the right direction!

Comment: Will provide more details in the answer due to limitation in comment size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how to achieve it. Effectively creating a brand new class, dettaching the former and attaching the latter does the job.

```
 var currentEmployee = _db.Employees.Single(x=>x.Id == employeeId);
 _db.Entry<Employee>(currentEmployee).State = EntityState.Detached;

 // create new one with the correct ID to update
 var updateEmployee = new Employee();
 updateEmployee.Id = currentEmployee.Id;                        

 // map values over and ensure EF is aware of modifications
 updateEmployee.FirstName = "John";
 updateEmployee.Surname = "Smith";                       
 _db.Entry<Employee>(updateEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified;
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Employee` is your entity with `Id, Name, Address, Age etc` and if you wanna update the `Name` and set others to empty, then - (assuming your employee id is 10) -

```
var employee = new Employee {Id = 10, Name = "Updated Name"};
dbContext.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Reply to the answer you have posted**
You don't necessarily have to do a fetch (get the entity from database) before updating. When you do a `var currentEmployee = _db.Employees.Single(x=>x.Id == employeeId);` - the entity is preserved in the context and any changes made to that entity will be tracked by the change tracker. Which means, if you update the name `currentEmployee.Name = "new name"` - change tracker will mark *only* this property as `Modified` and update will happen only for this property. You had to detach - `_db.Entry<Employee>(currentEmployee).State = EntityState.Detached;` as that entity has been attached to the context after the get.

I would suggest you to avoid the get/fetch request (avoid an unnecessary database hit) and update the property as I mentioned in my answer.

```
var employee = new Employee {Id = 10, Name = "Updated Name"};
dbContext.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The above code will work as you expect - make sure that the `Id = 10` is already present in the database, else this will throw error.

Just few additional info, in case you want to update the `Name` property alone and keep the others unchanged, then you could do something like below (this approach also avoids extra database hit for getting the entity):

```
var employee = new Employee {Id = 10};
dbContext.Employees.Attach(employee);
employee.Name = "Updated Name";
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or in case you already have an Employee object with updated name being received in your method, then:

```
//assuming employee object has an valid Id/primary key
Context.Entry(employee).Property(e=>e.Name).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: The problem is I already need to do a fetch on the record to get the id anyway.  The other thing is that if I don't do a fetch and just attach with the modified record, then it will still update the changed property, but all the other properties are still left in-tact in the database. I want to clear all other fields out.  Perhaps using Employee is a bad example, as my requirement is not a usual CRUD scenario.  Your above modified flag on each property may work, but this means having this line of code for every property. My solution is only a few lines long.